# A domain which is a left uniform but not a right uniform (or vice versa)

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with unity. Recall that $R$ is called **left uniform** if the intersection of any two nonzero left ideals is nonzero. Right uniform rings are defined analogously.

Does there exist a domain which is a left uniform but not a right uniform ?!, or a domain which is a right uniform but not a left uniform?!.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As usual, any example of a ring satisfying a "left but not right" property automatically turns into one satisfying the corresponding "right but not left" property and vice versa by taking the opposite ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for example, let $k$ be a division ring and $\sigma$ be an endomorphism of $K$ that isn't an automorphism.  The twisted polynomial ring $k[x,\sigma]$ (where multiplication is defined $x\lambda = \sigma(\lambda)x$) is left uniform but not right uniform (and its opposite ring is right uniform and not left uniform.)

It's also worth noting that a domain is left uniform iff it is a left Ore domain.

---

It is left uniform because it is a left principal ideal ring (but you can also make do with the weaker conditions that it is left Noetherian or left Bezout). It's not right uniform because you can find right ideals that intersect trivially. For example, take any $\lambda\in K\setminus \sigma(K)$, and $xR\cap \lambda xR=\{0\}$

---

Using the Bezout condition is not bad:

Suppose you have $Ra$ and $Rb$ for $a,b$ nonzero.   There exists a $c$ such that $Rd=Ra+Rb$.  This gets you $d=ra+sb$ and $a=td$.

Then $a=td=tra+tsb$, and rearanging to $(1-tr)a=tsb$. If $s$ were $0$, that would imply $Rc=Ra\supseteq Rb$, and we would be done. Otherwise $tsb$ is nonzero, and we have $Ra\cap Rb\neq \{0\}$.

Comment: Here is the [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=105l&H=8&L=105r) for your question. it has at least one more such example.

Comment: $\sigma$ is a ring endomorphism or a module endomorphism?. Also, what is meant by a twisted polynomial ring?. Where is the proof that $K[x,\sigma]$ is left uniform but not right uniform?.

Comment: @HusseinEid It's a ring endomorphism. This is the standard "twisted polynomial" or "Ore extension" construction. I will let you know when I find time to expand the post.

Comment: It is not obvious to me that the ring is left uniform. May you please write some details?.

Comment: @HusseinEid Ok there.

Comment: Why $Rc=Ra+Rb$?. Is $c=\gcd(a,b)$?. Why $a=td$?.

Comment: @HusseinEid The definition of "left Bezout" is that f.g. left ideals are principal. As for $c$ and $d$, sorry, I didn't realize I switched between characters. I need to use $d$ consistently.  It should be $d=ra+sb$ and $a=td$.  These are simply consequences of $Rd=Ra+Rb$ and $Ra\subseteq Rd$.